# Signing key fingerprints do not match our records for this app

Tags: android, firebase, google-pay, firebase-app-distribution

I recently integrated firebase app distribution and i'm uploading AABs.
Thing is that firebase resigning my app with a different signature, and some of my integrations with google were failed.

Google pay - i'm getting the following error when trying to pay with Google Pay:

```
Signing key fingerprints {**:**:**.....} do not match our records for this app.
```

Which make sense, because there was only one signature to work with so far.

How can I add the key of the resigned signature of firebase app distribution?

Thanks for assisting.